# Custom Library Directory for Ruby

Tags: ruby, path

I have a directory that has inside of it my custom libraries for Ruby. What is the best way to add this directory to the library paths for Ruby? I don't want to do this on the executed Ruby file. I used to do this by leaving a symbolic link for each library in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1`, and am looking for a better way.

- OS: Linux Mint 13
- Ruby: 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RUBYLIB`. Add to `.bashrc` or wherever:

```
export RUBYLIB=/path/to/whatever/
```

[RUBYLIB Environment Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995305/rubylib-environment-path)